# Is there a word meaning 'someone who is a source of money?'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Not in the breadwinner or sugar daddy sense but someone you are being a parasite to.

Does cash cow apply here?

Comment: Far more context is needed, and a single-word-request requires an example sentence to put the word in.

Comment: A cash cow is not a person, but an entity such as a business or an investment. You need to provide more context in order to get a proper response.

Comment: The obvious parallel to 'parasite' is 'host'.

Comment: Not a bad question, this. I thought it would be easily Googlable, with "antonym for leech" etc, but nothing useful comes up.

Comment: in some contexts ***sugar daddy*** is applicable in others the metonym ***checkbook*** might work or ***benefactor***

Answer (score 1):

**Meal ticket**:

> A person or thing depended on as a source of financial support. - [American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Meal+ticket)

**Gravy Train**:

> source of income that requires little effort while yielding considerable profit. - [Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gravy+train)

Answer (score 0):

*ATM* and the pleonastic *ATM machine* are sometimes used like that, especially by parents and romantic partners. The typical usage is a response like "I am not an ATM" or "do I look an ATM machine?" after the parasite asks for money.